# Kernel density smoothing in d3.js

Tags: d3.js

Apologies as I am an expert in neither statistics nor d3.js.

I am trying to overlay two smoothed histograms to show overlap in two related distributions.

I am wondering about the availability of kernel density or other smoothing in d3.js.  There seemed to be some activity on the topic about a year ago, but I am not able to find the function in the mainline d3.js code.  (The Wikipedia entry on kernel density estimation suggests d3's "science.stats" functions, which are not in my d3.v2.js download.)

Was it incorporated into the histogram layout with the density option?  Or is it not available currently?

Answer (score 11):

The example you are looking for is in the [kde folder](https://github.com/jasondavies/science.js/tree/master/examples/kde) of the [science.js](https://github.com/jasondavies/science.js) git repository, which includes the kernel estimator.

Here's what it looks like:
[image: screenshot of kde.js in action]

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking at the examples that uses d3js to render a Kernel Density Estimation graph. They are helpful but I have not found an example that clearly explains how to choose the optimal domain in the first place for both X and Y axes.

For example, in the example that uses Old Faithful, the optimal domain for the X axis is already defined as [30, 110]. How could someone come up with that domain first?

```
x = d3.scale.linear().domain([30, 110]).range([0, w]),**
```

The same goes for the Y axis too.

```
y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, .1]).range([0, h]),
```

How would someone know that the domain would be [0, .1] even before calculating the Kernel Density Estimation?