# Joining functions to DOM elements in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying out D3.js to produce kernel density estimates (rather than exporting the estimates from python) of different distributions so that I can overly them on top of each other.

From a  [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10902729/kernel-density-smoothing-in-d3-js), I was directed to  [this](https://github.com/jasondavies/science.js/blob/master/examples/kde/kde.js)  page showing an example how to do it,

I am having trouble understanding the data joining part of the example. The author joins `science.stats.bandwidth` to his `path` elements but he does not appear to use it at all. The `"d"` attribute of `path` is being set without referring to the bound function/data.

I also want to use only one of the bandwidth functions in `science.stats.bandwidth`. I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction.

My modfications from the linked example so far are as follows:

```
sa=vis.selectAll(".cat")
.data(result)
.enter()
.append("g")
.attr("class", "category");

count = 0;
sa.each(function(){
sb = d3.select(this);
sb.selectAll(".path")
.data(d3.values(science.stats.bandwidth))
.enter()
.append("path")
.attr("stroke", function(d){return color(d)})
.attr("d", function(h) {
    return line(allKde[count].bandwidth(h)(d3.range(<lowerExtent>,<higherExtent>,1)));
  })
count = count + 1;
});
```

Result is a list of dictionaries that looks like `[{'a':'<name>','b':<array of numbers>}...]`. 
allKde is a list of KDEs, each of which are produced by `science.stats.kde().sample(result<index>.b)`

Comment: I have added what I have done so far. It produces two Kernel Density estimations for each item on `result`. I would like to produce just one Kernel Density Estimation for each item, and also ideally have `result` itself bound to `path` so that I can add a legend. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The anonymous function to set the svg path's `d` attribute is indeed using the bound data:

```
.attr("d", function(h) {
  return line(allKde[count].bandwidth(h)(d3.range(<lowerExtent>,<higherExtent>,1)));
})
```

This might be confusing since it uses `h` instead of `d`, which is more common in d3 examples.

There also seems to be some non-standard use of indices in this example which may be confusing. (the count variable being used to define the line)

If you want to append just one line for a single element of `science.stats.bandwidth`, you should be able to simply bind that one element of data: `science.stats.bandwidth[0]` for instance